# Rename Files - Only After All Have been opened (to ensure links update to new file location and names)

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I have 50 files that are linked to each other to varying degrees. Each month all files must be moved to a different folder (new issue) with updated names to reflect the new month (ie. Sales 445F - 06-2019 to Sales 446F - 07-2019).

To do so, I believe I need to open all 50 files, before renaming, so that the links will be updated to the new name and the new file location.

Below is the macro I created keying off a column that identifies the files to be opened and then a second column that identifies the new name of the file.

Although the macro creates new files in the right location with the right names, the files created are all the same (the last file opened) and the links still remain attached to the old file names and locations. Suggestions?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
For i = 10 To 59

pathname = Range("B5").Value
Filename = Range("B" & i).Value

Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Workbooks.Open Filename:=pathname & Filename

Next i

MsgBox ("All Files Have Been Opened")

For i = 10 To 59

pathname2 = Range("C5").Value
filename2 = Range("C" & i).Value

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=pathname2 & filename2

Next i

MsgBox ("All Files Have Been Saved in the New Folder. A Final Save to Update Links to Point to the New Folder Will Now Begin")

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wbStayOpen1 As String
    Dim currentwb As String
            
    wbStayOpen1 = "C:\Users\Desktop\Custom Macros\Open Rename and Save to New Folder.xlsm"
    currentwb = ThisWorkbook.Name
    
    For Each wb In Workbooks
    
    If wb.Name <> wbStayOpen1 And wb.Name <> currentwb Then
        
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
        End If
        
    Next wb

Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

1. It always saves the exact same workbook because you use `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs` and the active one does never change. Avoid using `ActiveWorkbook`. Instead set all workbooks to an array of opened workbooks `wbOpen(iStart To iEnd)` that you can easily access then in your second loop. And also use it to close them in your third loop.
2. **Never** number your variable names. This is a very bad practice and if you think you need to do that you are doing something wrong. Actually there is no need to declare `pathname2` and `filename2` you can re-use the first variable.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 'make sure to give it a proper name
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet 'better declare sheet name like `ThisWorkbook.Worsheets("Sheet1")
    
    'if the start and end is dynamic make them variables instead of constants
    Const iStart As Long = 10
    Const iEnd As Long = 59
    
    ReDim wbOpen(iStart To iEnd) As Workbook
    
    Dim PathName As String
    Dim FileName As String
    
    'open workbooks
    Dim i As Long
    For i = iStart To iEnd
        PathName = wsSource.Range("B5").Value
        FileName = wsSource.Range("B" & i).Value
    
        Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        
        Set wbOpen(i) = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=PathName & FileName)
    Next i
    
    MsgBox ("All Files Have Been Opened")
    
    'save workbooks
    For i = iStart To iEnd
        PathName = wsSource.Range("C5").Value
        FileName = wsSource.Range("C" & i).Value
    
        wbOpen(i).SaveAs FileName:=PathName & FileName
    Next i
    
    MsgBox ("All Files Have Been Saved in the New Folder.")
    
    'close workbooks
    For i = iStart To iEnd
        wbOpen(i).Close SaveChanges:=True
    Next i

    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```